# Regex find one or more character, including those with period or apostrophe or hypen in between. Without last symbol if it occur only once at end

Tags: python, regex

```
re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+(?=\'|\.|\-[A-Za-z]+)?', txt) 
re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\.\-]+(?:\'[A-Za-z]+)?',txt)
```

**Input**

```
txt = "which would find I'm U.S. co-op, include ending. without the . , but not ' - . rd- "
```

**expected_output**

```
['which', 'would', 'find', "I'm", "U.S.", 'co-op', 'include', 'ending', 'without', 'the', 'but', 'not', 'rd']
```

I tried the above and variations, but can't get it to work. How to do it?

Comment: It seems like you want to find words that have a hyphen, apostrophe, or period between the word's letters, but not as single punctuation marks, or words that end with any of those puctuation marks. You say "U.S." is a match, however, but it ends in a period.  Please clarify.

Comment: edited question for clarity

Comment: Is it safe to say you only want to capture the optional trailing dot **only** if there is another dot in the same word? Also, no dot to be captured I suppose with something like a line ending with `co-op.`

Comment: @JvdV yes you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for matches using `findall`:

```sh
\w+(?:['.-]\w+\.?)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ah5ukz/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:['.-]\w+\.?)?`: Optional non-capturing group that starts with a `'` or `.` or `-` followed by 1+ word characters and an optional trailing dot.

**Code:**

```py
import re
txt = "which would find I'm U.S. co-op, include ending. without the . , but not ' - . rd- "
print (re.findall(r"\b\w+(?:['.-]\w+\.?)?", txt))

['which', 'would', 'find', "I'm", 'U.S.', 'co-op', 'include', 'ending', 'without', 'the', 'but', 'not', 'rd']
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer! omitting the \b seems to give me the same output for this sample text. may I know when is best to use it?

Comment: It is just to make sure we start matchi from a word character, but you are right on this case it will work without word boundary as wee.

Comment: accepted the answer, but I still would like to know what would be the best use case for \b?

Comment: I have removed `\b` as it wasn't serving much purpose here.

Answer (score 1):

At risk of overthinking your actual issue, here is my attempt with the following assumptions:

- You only want to use alphachars `[A-Za-z]`.
- You don't want to match trailing dots in cases like `"let's play co-op."`.
- Lastly, my guess is you will also want to capture double hyphened words like `"non-English-speaking"` and abbreviations with more than just a single dot.

Thus, what I came up with is:

```
\b[a-z]+(?:(?:(\.)|['-])[a-z]+\1?)*
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IRzDC1/1).

- `\b` - A word boundary.
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ alphachars.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group:

  - `(?:` - Open 1nd non-capture group:

    - `(\.)|['-]` - A 1st capture group holding a dot **or** a hyphen or apostrophe.
    - `)[a-z]+\1?` - Close 2nd non-capture group, match 1+ alphachars and optionally match what is captured in the 1st capture group (thus a dot).
  - `)*` - Close 1st non-capture group and match 0+ times.

In Python, it could look like something like:

```
import re
txt = "which would find I'm U.S. co-op, include ending. without the . , but not ' - . rd- "
lst = [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r"\b[a-z]+(?:(?:(\.)|['-])[a-z]+\1?)*", txt, re.I)]
print(lst) # ['which', 'would', 'find', "I'm", 'U.S.', 'co-op', 'include', 'ending', 'without', 'the', 'but', 'not', 'rd']
```

Comment: thanks. it looks quite complex but I may reserve it for future use!